unexpected behavior of python threading.Condition
I'm trying to synchronize multiple threads. I expect script output when using threading.Condition and threading.Barrier will be about the same, but it's not. Please explain why this is happening.
In general, I need threads to perform work (some IO operation) in an infinite loop, but each cycle starts with the permission of the master thread, and permission is given only after the previous cycle is completed by all threads.
script 1
from threading import Barrier, Thread
from time import sleep, time

br = Barrier(3)
store = []

def f1():
    while True:
        br.wait()
        sleep(1)
        print("Calc part1")

def f2():
    while True:
        br.wait()
        sleep(1)
        print("Calc part2")


Thread(target=f1).start()
Thread(target=f2).start()

for i in range(10):
    br.wait()
    print(f'end iter {i}')
    print(f'-------------')

expected behavior
ent iter 0
-------------
Calc part1
Calc part2
ent iter 1
-------------
Calc part2
Calc part1
ent iter 2
-------------
Calc part1
...

script 2
from threading import Condition, Thread
from time import sleep

condition = False
cv = Condition()

def predicate():
    return condition

def f1():
    for i in range(3):
        with cv:
            cv.wait_for(predicate)
            sleep(1)
            print("Calc part1")

def f2():
    for i in range(3):
        with cv:
            cv.wait_for(predicate)
            sleep(1)
            print("Calc part2")


Thread(target=f1).start()
Thread(target=f2).start()

with cv:
    condition = True
    cv.notify_all()

unexpected behavior
Calc part1
Calc part1
Calc part1
Calc part2
Calc part2
Calc part2

Why stdout of threads not mixed in result of second script?

You expect the primitives of the threading module to be fair, i.e. that the thread that waited longer will acquire the underlying lock first. But, unfortunately, they do not provide such a guarantee, and the unfairness of threading.Condition is a known problem.
In your example, the first thread exits with cv, but enters again due to the loop, and does so without blocking. The reason is two things:

Due to the way the CPython interpreter works, a sequence like release()-acquire() has such a low chance of switching between these calls that it is almost impossible - the first thread will always be able to reacquire the lock, depriving the second thread of CPU time.
cv.wait_for() never releases the lock if predicate() is already True.

If you still want a fair Condition, you can try aiologic.Condition (I'm the creator of aiologic). Just replace from threading import Condition with from aiologic import Condition and you'll get the expected output:
Calc part1
Calc part2
Calc part1
Calc part2
Calc part1
Calc part2

But here's the thing: so far, cv.wait_for() is not fair. If you have a predicate that is True more often than not, as in your example, then this won't be a problem, but in the example from CPython's issue resource starvation will still occur. It will become fair in some future version of aiologic.
